# C++ strings not working

Tags: c++, string, constructor

I would like to make this programm show the "Gianna" "Maria" and "M" strings on the screen but I can't. There's no error so I guess there's something wrong with my programm. Any suggestions what could fix my programm?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class name
{
    string fName, mName, sName;
    public:
        name (string fName, string mName, string sName){};
        void setFName (string fName);
        void setMName (string mName);
        void setSName (string sName);
        string getFName() const {return fName;}
        string getSName() const {return sName;}
        string getMName() const {return mName;}
        friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &, const name &);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const name& n) {
    return os << n.fName << " " << n.sName<< " " << n.mName;
}

int main ()
{
    name myName ("Gianna", "Maria", "M");
    cout<<myName.getFName()<<" "<<myName.getMName()<<" "<<myName.getSName()<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `name (string fName, string mName, string sName)` -- It's not a good idea to name your parameters the same as your member variables.  That's probably why you thought that the constructor you wrote magically sets those member variables by matching the names -- nope, doesn't work that way.

Comment: In addition and offtopic you can use the operaror << of your class in cout line: `cout<<myName<<endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor:

```
    name (string fName, string mName, string sName){};
```

doesn't do anything. You need to use the parameters to initialise your member variables.

```
   name (string f, string m, string s)
         : fName(f), mName(m), sName(s)  {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize daya members of the class in the constructor.

Define the constructor the following way

```
name( const string &fName, const string &mName, const string &sName )
    : fName( fName ), mName( mName ), sName( sName )
{
}
```

Correspondingly these member functions should be defined like

```
    void setFName ( const string &fName)
    {
        this->fName = fName;
    }
    void setMName (const string &mName)
    {
        this->mName = mName;
    }
    void setSName (const string &sName)
    {
        this->sName = sName;
    }
```

There is no need to make the `operator <<` as a friend function of the class. It can be defined like

```
ostream& operator <<( ostream& os, const name& n ) {
    return os << n.getFName() << " " << n.getMName() << " " << n.getSName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor must assign the parameters you pass to the member variables, that doesn't happen automatically.

```
name (string fName, string mName, string sName) : fName(fName), mName(mName), sName(sName) {};
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much!!! :D

Comment: Well, not actually "assign" in this case.

Comment: @latedeveloper it's assigning values to those variables, even if it's technically not using assignment to do so. The distinction is far too subtle for me to think about normally.

Comment: I think the distinction between initialisation and assignment is a pretty key concept for a C++ programmer.

Comment: @latedeveloper I agree that it's important to be *aware* of the difference, it's just that it doesn't often matter in practice. In this case the only difference is whether a default constructor gets called on each of the strings, which in the end doesn't matter to the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

For your constructor, you have the three strings as your parameters but you aren't setting the member variables to their values. You can use an initializer list on the constructor like this...

```
name (string f, string m, string s) 
    : fName(f), mName(m), sName(s) // member(parameter) format
{

}
```

...or you can implement the `setter` stubs you have...

```
void setFName(string name) { this->fName = name;}
```

... and use them inside of your constructor like...

```
name (string fName, string mName, string sName) {
    setFName(fName);
    //...
}
```

Comment: @Slava if i remember currently, the outer value is assumed as class-level variables and not looked for locally (in the function/constructor/etc). Perhaps it is best to switch the names of the parameters to be safe...

Answer (score 0):

Basically the parameters passed in the constructor are getting lost since you are not assigning it to the class vars..

Do something like:

```
name (string f, string m, string s) : fName(f), mName(m), sName(s){....};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. You forgot to implement Constructor of the class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
class name
{
    string sFName, sMName, sSName;
    public:
        name (string FName, string MName, string SName);
        void Display();
        void setFName (string fName);
        void setMName (string mName);
        void setSName (string sName);
        string getFName() const {return sFName;}
        string getSName() const {return sSName;}
        string getMName() const {return sMName;}

};

name::name(string FName, string MName, string SName )
{
    sFName = FName;
    sMName = MName;
    sSName = SName;
}

void name::setFName(string fName)
{
      sFName = fName;
}

void name::setMName(string mName)
{
      sMName = mName;
}

void name::setSName(string sName)
{
      sSName = sName;
}

void name::Display()
{
    cout<< sFName<< endl;
    cout<< sMName<< endl;
    cout<< sSName<< endl;
}
int main ()
{
    name myName ("Gianna", "Maria", "M");
    myName.Display();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP did implement the constructor. Unfortunately the implementation doesn't do anything.